# Just a little question about logic. Why are these equivalent?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, return, boolean-logic

Thought I would start learning to code again so quick question. Why and how is this:

```
if (n1 >= 13 && n1 <= 19 || n2 >= 13 && n2 <= 19 || n3 >= 13 && n3 <= 19) {
            return true;
    }
```

and this:

```
return n1 >= 13 && n1 <= 19 || n2 >= 13 && n2 <= 19 || n3 >= 13 && n3 <= 19;
```

Equivalent? Anyone want to explain the logic to me?

Comment: They're not equivalent.

Comment: In the first case it will return true only if the condition satisfies, it won't return anything when the condition is not satisfied. In the second case, it will return true and false both.

Comment: Are you missing `return false;` after the `if` in the first case?

Comment: They're not equivalent at all. The first evaluates an expression and returns an hardcoded `true` value if, and only if, said expression evaluates to `true`.
The second returns the value of an expression.

Also, the first will let the program carry on if the tested expression evaluates to false; same can't be said for the second statement.

Comment: As an aside, if your condition gets bigger you may consider doing `if(IntStream.of(n1,n2,n3,...).anyMatch(n -> n => 13 && n <= 19)){...}`

Answer (score 1):

In your 1st version if the expression:

```
(n1 >= 13 && n1 <= 19 || n2 >= 13 && n2 <= 19 || n3 >= 13 && n3 <= 19)
```

is `true` then `true` is returned, if its `false` then nothing is returned.  
Your 2nd version returns the value of the above expression `true` or `false`.  
So they're not equivalent.  
If you change the 1st version to:

```
if (n1 >= 13 && n1 <= 19 || n2 >= 13 && n2 <= 19 || n3 >= 13 && n3 <= 19) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

then they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The first will only return `true` if the condition is `true` whereas the second will return the result regardless.

To answer your question, they're equivalent in the sense that both approaches would yield the same boolean result when the condition `n1 >= 13 && n1 <= 19 || n2 >= 13 && n2 <= 19 || n3 >= 13 && n3 <= 19` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the if statement,

```
if(condition)
```

the result of a `condition` of a if statement will be a boolean, as the method's return type is also `boolean` you can return the condition's result instead of coding manually.

Now your following statement is considered as a `condition`,

```
(n1 >= 13 && n1 <= 19 || n2 >= 13 && n2 <= 19 || n3 >= 13 && n3 <= 19)
```

it may return either `true` or `false`. Both of them are `boolean`s. So you can put that directly with `return`.

---

However, you haven't mentioned what will happen if the given condition fails or return `false`. Your code may have some other lines after the if statement. In such case it won't be equivalent, and will give a compile error saying `unreachable statement` after,

```
return n1 >= 13 && n1 <= 19 || n2 >= 13 && n2 <= 19 || n3 >= 13 && n3 <= 19;
```